# Android setting CID / LAC

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

Is there any implemented solutions for **setting** LAC/SAC or CID manually ?
From Telephony api I see getting LAC CID (TelephonyManager  getLAC(), getCID()) is possible but do not see setting them. 
I checked may be it is possible on RIL layer, but was not able to find any example as Vendor RIL seems to do the job.

Thanks in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want this? CID/LAC comes from the network, i.e. it is an environmental property. The only reason to set them would be for testing purposes, and in that case you should be looking at mocks rather than injecting values into the real telephony layer.

Comment: Actually I need that for testing. Need to set to specific ARFCN as in Nokia S60 Field Test application